# Return top 5 rated computers

Tags: r

We asked people to rate, among 5 computers, which is their favorite. For each person, I want to get their top 3 ratings.

Sample Data:

```
Apple <-         c(1,2,3,4,5)
Dell <-          c(2,1,4,3,3)
Samsung <-       c(3,5,1,2,4)
Acer <-          c(4,4,2,1,1)
ChromeBook <-    c(5,3,5,5,2)
RespondentID <-  c(1,2,3,4,5)
df <- data.frame(RespondentID,Apple, Dell, Samsung,Acer, ChromeBook)
```

What I hope to get is, for each respondent, what is the top 3 computers.

So essentially, for each row, how I do return the column names for the top 3 rated computers?

RespondentID FirstChoice  Second Choice  ThirdChoice
1             Apple           Dell        Samsung
2             Dell            Apple       Chromebook
.
.
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gather()` and `spread()` to better frame your data.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% gather(Computer, Rating, -RespondentID)

   RespondentID   Computer Rating
1             1      Apple      1
2             2      Apple      2
3             3      Apple      3
4             4      Apple      4
5             5      Apple      5
6             1       Dell      2
7             2       Dell      1
8             3       Dell      4
9             4       Dell      3
10            5       Dell      3
```

You can then filter to only ratings 3 or higher, and then spread it back to columns.

```
df %>% 
    gather(Computer, Rating, -RespondentID) %>% 
    filter(Rating >= 3) %>% 
    spread(Rating, Computer) %>%
    select(RespondentID, 
           FirstChoice = `5`, 
           SecondChoice = `4`, 
           ThirdChoice = `3`)

  RespondentID FirstChoice SecondChoice ThirdChoice
1            1  ChromeBook         Acer     Samsung
2            2     Samsung         Acer  ChromeBook
3            3  ChromeBook         Dell       Apple
4            4  ChromeBook        Apple        Dell
5            5       Apple      Samsung        Dell
```

Comment: no problem @ray. Could you click the green check box to accept the answer please!?